# pagination doesn't work in search page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

halo guys, my pagination can't work under search page. i made custom search page and the link will be like this

`/search/?category=2&tag=all`

when i click next link. the link become this

`/search/page/2/?category=2&tag=all`

but post didn't change. when i var_dump `get_query_var('paged');` it always return 0. how do i can resolve this.

here is my code in display post

```
<?php

                    $CurrentPage = get_query_var('paged');

                    $args = [
                        'posts_per_page' => 2,
                        'paged' => $CurrentPage,
                        'cat' =>  $search_category,
                        'tag' =>  $search_tag,

                    ];
                    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

                    if ($loop->have_posts()) :
                        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                        $image = get_field('thumbnail');
                ?>
```

here is for display pagination

```
<?php previous_posts_link('<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/static/images/column/arrow01.svg" alt="prev">PREV', $loop->max_num_pages) ?>

<?php list_pagination($loop); ?>

<?php next_posts_link('NEXT<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/static/images/column/arrow02.svg" alt="next">', $loop->max_num_pages); ?>
```

here is my code in functions.php

```
function list_pagination($loop) {
   $big = 999999999;
   $paged = paginate_links(array(
       'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
       'format' => '?paged=%#%',
       'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
       'prev_next'          => false,
       'type'               => 'array',
       'add_fragment'       => '',
       'before_page_number' => '',
       'after_page_number'  => '',
       'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
   ));

    if ( ! empty( $paged ) ) :
                echo '<ul class="pager_list">';
                    $no = 1;
                     foreach ( $paged as $key => $page_link ) : 
                        echo '<li class="pager_item">'.$page_link .'</li>';
                    endforeach;
                echo '</ul>';
            endif;

}
```

anywrong with my code?

Comment: do someone can figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

`$CurrentPage = get_query_var('paged');` should be changed to `$CurrentPage = get_query_var('page');` i.e. without d at the end of paged.

Comment: thank you for answering. but the problem still same. it won't change the post